# Spring Boot H2 db for testing throws "Table not found(this database is empty)" and "SQLGrammarException"

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, junit, h2

I'm trying to write `JUnit` using embedded `h2` in memory `db`. We are using `MS SQL` for live connection.

Below are the files.

*application.properties*:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.user=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=true;MODE=MySQL
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

*test class*:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SqlServerConfig.class },loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@Transactional
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@Rollback
public class JPACriteriaQueryTest {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    private Category category;



    @Test
    public void givenFirstAndLastName_whenGettingListOfUsers_thenCorrect() {
        Category category=new Category();
        category.id("10");
        category.setDeptId("21031");
        category.repType("7");
        category.save(category);

}}
```

save method over here is throwing exception

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2122)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2059)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2037)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:956)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2440)
        
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "CATEGORY" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
```

I have checked my entity and there is no usage of any reserved `SQL` keyword.

Can anyone, please, help on this.